# How to pad a RGB image with RGB values using numpy.pad

Tags: python, numpy, padding, pad

I'm trying to pad a RGB image with magenta (255, 0, 255) color with `np.pad`. But I'm getting an error when using RGB values as `constant_values`. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import face
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def pad_img(img, pad_with):
    pad_value = max(img.shape[:-1])
    img_padded = np.pad(img,
                        ((0, (pad_value - img.shape[0])),  # pad bottom
                         (0, (pad_value - img.shape[1])),  # pad right
                         (0, 0)),  # don't pad channels
                        mode='constant',
                        constant_values=pad_with)

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    ax1.imshow(img)
    ax2.imshow(img_padded)
    plt.show()
```

This works fine (padding with white color):

```py
img = face()
pad_img(img, pad_with=255)
```

[image: out1]

And this not (padding with magenta):

```py
img = face()
pad_img(img, pad_with=(255, 0, 255))
```

Throwing:

> `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,) and requested shape (3,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
img = face()
pad_img(img, pad_with=(((255, 0, 255), (255, 0, 255)), ((255, 0, 255), (255, 0, 255)), (0, 0)))
```

According to [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) `constant_values` is of form:

*`((before_1, after_1), ... (before_N, after_N))`*

And I think that is why the error says it gets shape `(3,)` (`(255, 0, 255)`) for `pad_width` while it requests shape `(3,2)` (`(((255, 0, 255), (255, 0, 255)), ((255, 0, 255), (255, 0, 255)), (0, 0))`)

Comment: OP seems to want to use `(255, 0, 255)` as the constant values to pad with

Comment: @yatu yes i want to pad w/ magenta

Comment: Yes! `(((255, 0, 255), (255, 0, 255)), ((255, 0, 255), (255, 0, 255)), (0, 0))`  works fine, @Ehsan please edit the answer and I will accept it!

Comment: Nice @trsvchn ! :)

Comment: Oh, I though that you want to pad each width and height with 255 and depth with 0. Now I understand your question. Editing accordingly.